# Is it possible to generate all stake pool files and keys using Cardano Serialization Lib?

Tags: cardano-cli, stake-pool, cardano-serialization-lib, cardano-address

To successfully create and register a stake pool, we are require to generate:

- Payment keys and address
- Stake keys and address
- Stake pool cold key
- Stake pool hot key
- Stake pool VRF key
- Stake pool operational certificate

We can do all this using `cardano-cli`.

Is it possible to do it using https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible at the moment.

I have found this commit of the `cardano-multiplatform-lib` that starts giving some support for these kind of tasks related to generating different types of certificates (stake pool ones included):

https://github.com/dcSpark/cardano-multiplatform-lib/commit/d9ec0ce32136deda2a497dd1c04e6dce8932ba5a

The PR is in progress yet. We will need to wait a little more for dcSpark team, in order to have full support for this feature.

In the meanwhile, I suggest using [`cardanocli-js`](https://github.com/shareslake/cardanocli-js) to generate stake pool certificates.

Like this:

```
const CardanocliJs = require("cardanocli-js");

const shelleyGenesisPath = "/path/to/your/testnet-shelley-genesis.json";
const options = {
  shelleyGenesisPath,
  network: "testnet-magic 1097911063"
};

const cardanocliJs = new CardanocliJs(options);

const nodeKeyGenKES = cardanocliJs.nodeKeyGenKES(stakePoolName);
const nodeKeyGen = cardanocliJs.nodeKeyGen(stakePoolName);
const nodeOperationalCert = cardanocliJs.nodeIssueOpCert(stakePoolName);
const vrfKeyAccount = cardanocliJs.nodeKeyGenVRF(stakePoolName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link about generating keys:
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-serialization-lib/generating-keys